# Facebook app random error (not showing the reason)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make an app, here's my code so far: http://pastebin.com/wGPqqQpF

While it works fine for me, but 2 other people see this error:

http://screencast.com/t/IIk6coTqt

one of them is added to the administrators list

Facebook isn't being helpful by mentioning the reason of the error *shrug*

any help is very appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the facebook api

```
$fb = array();
$fb['appID'] = 'xxx'; //real ap id and secret code were here
$fb['secret'] = 'xxx';
$fb['cookie'] = true;
$facebook = new Facebook($fb)
```

this is not the way

This question has been asked many times, if you search for this topic you will get to know....

The right way is as follows

```
define('APP_ID','xxx');// Facebook App Id
define('API_KEY','xxx');// Facebook App Id
define('APP_SECRET','xxx');// Facebook Secret Key
define('APP_ONETIMECODE','xxx');// Facebook Secret Key

define('APP_COOKIE',true);// Facebook Cookie
define('APP_REQPERMS','email,publish_stream,status_update,user_location');

define('APP_NAME','YOUR APP NAME');// Facebook APP Name
define('SITE_URL',"http://YourURL.COM");

define('CANVAS_NAME','xxxx');// Facebook 
define('CANVAS_PAGE','https://apps.facebook.com/xxxx/');
define('CANVAS_URL','xxxx');

define('CONTACT_EMAIL','xxxx@xxxx.com');
define('SUPPORT_EMAIL','xxxx@xxxx.com');


define('MAX','15');
define('MIN','5');
define('APP_DEBUG',true);

require './lib/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => APP_ID,'secret' => APP_SECRET,'cookie'=>APP_COOKIE));
if (!session_id()) { session_start(); }
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with my way, and that wasn't the problem, just in case anyone crosses such a problem, i replaced:
    `top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'";` 
with 
    `top.location.href = "actual/dialog/0auth_link";`